# Modelling One To One mapping with a polymorphic class in hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have the following model - a user entity which has a user profile. Depending on the role of the user, user profile varies. I have tried to model this one to one mapping between user and user profile using the shared primary key as per this [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-using-annotations/)

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(updatable = false,nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long userId;
  private String role;
  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private UserProfile profile;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(unique = true,nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "gen",strategy = "foreign",
      parameters = @Parameter(name = "property",value = "user"))
  private Long userId;
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "profile")
  private User user;
}

@Entity
public class DeviceUserProfile extends UserProfile {
  private Long deviceId;
}

@Entity
public class AdminUserProfile extends UserProfile {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
```

But when I insert the user entity, the user profile is not being added to the corresponding table.

```
User user1 = new User();
user1.setRole("Device");

DeviceUserProfile deviceUserProfile = new DeviceUserProfile();
deviceUserProfile.setDeviceId(1234L);

user1.setProfile(deviceUserProfile);
deviceUserProfile.setUser(user1);

session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user1);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Any pointers on how to solve this or if my model could be better would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved after I added `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` at `User.profile` and `UserProfile.user` as follows

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(updatable = false,nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long userId;
  private String role;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private UserProfile profile;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(unique = true,nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "gen",strategy = "foreign",
      parameters = @Parameter(name = "property",value = "user"))
  private Long userId;
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "profile",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private User user;
}
```